# maven jaxws-maven-plugin not adding generated packaged build path

Tags: java, maven

I use `mvn compile` and I have a pom that uses **jaxws-maven-plugin** to create client classes, which it does fine. I get all my classes inside `target>generated-sources>wsimport>` path. But the classes aren't being added to my classpath. So my project does not compile.

plugin in pom.xml

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                  <goal>wsimport</goal>
               </goals>
              <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <packageName>org.tempuri</packageName>
                     <vmArgs>
                       <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                                  </vmArgs>
                                  <!-- needs extension true otherwise wont generate trade web service stub. Still shows error SOAP binding 1.2 -->
                        <extension>true</extension>
                   </configuration>
                 </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the version of the plugin jaxws-maven-plugin. For some reason I was using version `2.3.1-b20150201.124`8. When I changed to`2.3` it worked fine.

The old version generated the proxy classes just fine but it did not add to classpath in Eclipse. There were no errors, But when I opened the project in Netbeans when I tried to generated the proxy classes from WSDL I got the error

> No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.impl.ArtifactDescriptorReader
>   was bound.

So I changed version of the plugin like this answer said:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277703/1754020

and it worked fine.